# Object returned in awaiting state

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, async-await

I have async and await implementation in my code. I want to add the object to list. the objects returned are sometimes in waiting state. My code is below

```
foreach (var obj in listobject)
{
    Task<Item> item = client.GetItemAsync(obj );
    information.Add(new clsinform
    {
        param1 = item.Property
    });
}
```

So, it crashes because the item object is still in waiting state. Please suggest what should be done to get the item object?

```
var imagedata = await client.GetPlayerImageAsync(obj);
using (Image x = (Bitmap)((new ImageConverter()).ConvertFrom(imagedata)))
{
    picPlayer.Image = x;
}
```

Crashing at code `picPlayer.Image = x;` . Here picPlayer is the PictureBox Control

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the syntax should be `Task<Item> item = await client.GetItemAsync(auctionInfo);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to `await` the value:

```
foreach (var obj in listobject)
{
    Item item = await client.GetItemAsync(auctionInfo);
    information.Add(new clsinform
    {
        param1 = item.Property
    });
}
```

Note that this requires the method itself to be flagged `async`.

Comment: @PKKG You should stick to one question per question.  What's the exception you're receiving at that line?